# Use RestSharp to check if gzip is enabled

Tags: c#, http, gzip, restsharp

I want to use RestSharp to check if certain websites have Gzip enabled. How can I achieve this? I cannot find anything helpful on the response object.

The `ContentEncoding` property is empty, and the `RawBytes.Length` corresponds to the unzipped size (I've tested on a site that I know uses gzip compression).

I use the latest version of RestSharp.

So what do I look for?

Comment: You could try [Accept-Encoding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Encoding). If you pretend to only understand GZIP you can try to force the server to use it (or whatever happens if it doesn't support it).

Comment: RestSharp automatically adds the Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate on all requests. But as far as I can tell, that doesn't tell me if the response is gzipped?

Comment: You might have to do this low-level. RestSharp automates content negotiation and other bothersome tasks for you. Using a high level library to get low-level info might not be that easy.

Comment: You can of course always take a look at [the source](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp) to find out if that info is available.